# Callback that didn't need parameters - why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

So, I have been working on this 2-part problem and managed to solve it, however I have some questions on how the code actually works - specifically the nature of the callback function. Below are the 2 parts of the problem laid out, along with my solution to both. I was able to solve the first part rather easily, but the second was much more challenging for me.

```js
// FIRST PART OF PROBLEM

var merge = function(array1, array2, callback){  
  //your code here.
}

var x = merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(a, b){  
  return a + b;
});

//x should now equal [6, 8, 10, 12].


// MY SOLUTION: 
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback){
  var newArray = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = callback(array1[i], array2[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

var x = merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(a, b){  
  return a + b;
}); // x equals [6, 8, 10, 12].
```

Now here is the second part of the problem that I was able to solve, but where I am having trouble is in specifically walking through the code step by step. My question is - why did I not need to give the callback parameter to the merge function any parameters? When I did attempt to provide parameter, x became NaN.

euclidian distance = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2))."

```js
var euclid = function(coords1, coords2){  
  //Your code here.
  //You should not use any loops and should
  //instead use your original merge function.
}

var x = euclid([1.2, 3.67], [2.0, 4.4]);

//x should now equal approximately 1.08.


// My solution:
var euclid = function(coords1, coords2){
 // // why does function() below require no parameters?
  var merged = merge(coords1, coords2, function() {
    return (coords1[0] - coords2[0]) * (coords1[0] - coords2[0]) +
    (coords1[1] - coords2[1]) * (coords1[1] - coords2[1]);
  });
  
  return Math.sqrt(merged[0]);
};

var x = euclid([1.2, 3.67], [2.0, 4.4]); //x does equal approximately 1.08.
```

I'm a newbie to programming, so I realize this is probably a rather trivial question. But any help with walking me through how the callback is actually working in this solution would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why did I not need to give the callback parameter to the merge function any parameters?

Given:

```
var euclid = function(coords1, coords2){

  // why does function() below require no parameters?
  var merged = merge(coords1, coords2, function() {
    return (coords1[0] - coords2[0]) * (coords1[0] - coords2[0]) +
    (coords1[1] - coords2[1]) * (coords1[1] - coords2[1]);
  });

  return Math.sqrt(merged[0]);
};
```

The (callback) function passed to the *merge* function has a closure to the variables of its outer scope. Including *coords1* and *coords2* in the formal parameter list of *Euclid* makes them local variables, so they don't need to be passed to the callback.

If the function was created outside the scope of *Euclid*, then you'd need to pass them (or reference them some other way).

Incidentally, I prefer function declarations to assignment of expressions, e.g.

```
function euclid(coords1, coords2) {
  // code here
}
```

as it makes it more obvious what the function's name is. Consider:

```
var foo = function fred() {
  // foo or fred in here
};

 // only foo out here
```

Comment: Perfect, makes total sense now. Thank you!!

Comment: Great answer, you can remember thinking that nested blocks always see their ancestors variables, as long as they don't redefine them.

Answer (score 1):

The second solution can be said to use `merge` only trivially. It's like that old question - how do you measure height of a building using an ammeter and a stopwatch? Throw the ammeter from the roof, measure time till pavement.

Your `merge` function will invoke its callback twice, the callback will calculate the full Euclid distance for the two-size arrays, and it will do it twice (so you'll get `[1.08, 1.08]` for the result of the merge; then you pick one of the results.

So your `merge` is a) unnecessary, b) inefficient, and c) doesn't work for any number of elements but 2.

---

The real solution involves noticing that Euclid distance is a sum; and each element of the sum only involves matching elements from two arrays: `a[i] - b[i]` squared. That should be your callback; and `merge` should give you an array like `[0.64, 0.53]`.

The real problem is - how do you sum an array when you can't use loops, only your `merge`? If you are guaranteed that there will be only two dimensions, it is easy. If not, you will have to cheat.

```
var euclid = function(aa, bb) {
  var squares = merge(aa, bb, function(a, b) {
    return (a - b) * (a - b);
  });
  return Math.sqrt(squares.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }));
};
```

Look, ma, no loops! (At least no overt ones.)

---

If you really want to only use `merge`, you will need to cheat harder.

```
var euclid = function(aa, bb) {
  var sum = 0;
  var squares = merge(aa, bb, function(a, b) {
    sum += (a - b) * (a - b);
    return null;
  });
  return Math.sqrt(sum);
};
```

Comment: Ah very cool, thanks, @Amadan. I figured using the 'merge' function was rather inefficient (but I had to use it in the context of the question/problem). Seeing the above implementation is very helpful.

Comment: It is efficient in my implementations, where it does what it is supposed to do (element-wise square of difference). In yours, it is being called twice, doing exactly the same job (sum of all squares of differences).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wasn't clear. Meant to say that my implementation using 'merge' was inefficient. Seeing your 2 versions above really makes me facepalm for not initially realizing how much unnecessary work took place in my solution!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you're getting confused because your `callback` is not a callback and thus shouldn't be named this way. You rather wanna name it `resolver`, or `calculator`: the function one need to provide is not intended to be called **back** right after the process, but rather to be called **while** resolving, thus the naming concern. The pattern of providing a `calculator` function parameter is when you want to give the ability of customizing your function behavior to the caller.

So, the only reason they didn't tell you to make the `euclid` function accept a `resolver` parameter is... well, they didn't want you to create a behavior-customizable function. That simple =D

Comment: Hmm, but I thought that 'callback' as defined in the first part of the problem IS acting as a true callback, is it not? The callback is passed as a parameter to the 'merge' function, and then the callback is called inside that merge function, right?

I think I'm confused as to how the 3rd parameter of the 'euclid' function simply doesn't need parameters. Can you explain how that part is specifically working? Thx!

Comment: @learningnow—that is indeed how the term "callback" is used in the ECMAScript language specification (e.g. [*every*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.every)), though Cyril's view is a reasonable alternative.

Comment: Hmm so I think I may now understand why the 3rd parameter of the 'euclid' function can't use parameters - it is because the 1st and 2nd parameters of the 'euclid' function already define them (coords1 and coords2). 

The anonymous function here has access to has access to the outer function's parameters at all times. Am I on the right track or completely off?