# Creating a function using callback

Tags: javascript, math, callback

I'm trying to understand how callback functions work properly by solving this problem:

> Complete the following merge function such that is behaves as
>   described in the example below. Merge should take two arrays of
>   numbers of identical length and a callback function.

```
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback){  
  //your code here.
}

var x = merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(a, b){  
  return a + b;
});

//x should now equal [6, 8, 10, 12].
```

> Now, use your merge function to complete the euclid function defined
>   below. Euclid should take two arrays, each of which has an equal
>   number of numerical elements, and return the euclidean distance
>   between them. For a quick refresher on what Euclidean distance is,
>   check here

```
var euclid = function(coords1, coords2){  
  //Your code here.
  //You should not use any loops and should
  //instead use your original merge function.
}

var x = euclid([1.2, 3.67], [2.0, 4.4]);

//x should now equal approximately 1.08.
```

I'm able to do this without callbacks, but ultimately I want to know how to complete a function like this using callback as a parameter.

Comment: in the top code, you would put something like `callback(v1, v2)` to call the function `function(a, b){...}` supplied

Comment: Something nearly identical to this was asked a few days ago [Callback that didn't need parameters - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644132/callback-that-didnt-need-parameters-why/32644595#32644595).  This must be some kind of homework.  It looks like this is the source: http://www.codewars.com/kumite/557c70c5830c19074200005a?sel=557c70c5830c19074200005a

Comment: This is from an individual's blog. Not homework for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go..

```js
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback) {
  var result = [];
  if (array1.length === array2.length) {
    while (array1.length > 0) {
      result.push(callback.call(null, array1.shift(), array2.shift()));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var euclid = function(coords1, coords2) {
  var x = merge(coords1, coords2, function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  })
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x[0], 2) + Math.pow(x[1], 2));
}

console.log(euclid([1.2, 3.67], [2.0, 4.4]));
```

Comment: On the result.push part of the code, why is the first parameter null for callback.call? Could this be done instead with just callback?

Comment: Fisrt argument is context, here we dont need to pass any context to callback. please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call